# Working with string and replace

Tags: c#

Ok So i have something like this:

```
String str = "Have.Fun.Something";
String str2 = "asd.sad.saw.sa.Something";
```

and i wanna remove all things from last char until first "." so output will be always

> Something

Comment: i tryied str.Replace("Have.Fun.", "")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
str = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('.')+1);
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
str.Split('.').Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a whole bunch of useful methods on an instance of a string. The best place for you to look is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx).

In your particular case you can use substring and lastindexof. If the case were more complicated I'd probably suggest RegEx although this is much more involved.

```
String str2 = str.SubString(str.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Comment: Or exception, if no '.' would be found.

Comment: @Lorond: Indeed although I'm not sure the answer needs exception handling in this case. It would make the answer more complicated and I'm not sure the poster needs the extra complexity, but +1 for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Split function Below like this :

```
String str = "Have.Fun.Something";
String str2 = "asd.sad.saw.sa.Something";

string[] Words= str.Split('.');

MessageBox.Show(Words[Words.Length-1].tostring());
```

Get Below like this

Something

Same as String str2 = "asd.sad.saw.sa.Something";
Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

You may use Regular Expressions (regex):

```
(?:.*)\.(?<myGroup>.*)
```

Applying the above regex, you'll have a group named 'myGroup' which has the value after the last dot

Personally, i like this options because it gives you further scalability if the need arises

If you need further assistance with regex, please say so

Answer (score 0):

Bug free approach

```
public static string Substring(string input)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        int lastIndex = input.LastIndexOf('.');
        if (lastIndex != -1)
            return input.Substring(lastIndex + 1);
    }

    return input;
}
```

Comment: Is it really bug free? What would it do for "Hello."